# How to get a bar plot with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I want to plot a bar chart for a list of items. It is a list of string names with frequencies (int) The list is quite long, so I can not manually edit it.

```
[]                       4291017
['a']                    221943
['b']                    121027
['d']                    100915
['c']                    54344
['g']                    33486
```

The above was an output of the following command:
names = df['names'].explode().value_counts().head(N)

The plot command that I am using is:

```
names.plot(kind='barh')
```

How can I plot it for all the values except for the first one, which is basically an empty field? The problem is that I cannot drop it as it is not NaN.

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `print(df[['names']].head(10))` please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
names = df['names'].explode().value_counts().iloc[1:]
```

will remove the first line (`[]`)

Comment: It works, thank you so much. It also works if I do the .iloc in the next command. For, example, names_new = names.iloc[1:]

Comment: Yes it works everywhere. You can also use `names.iloc[1:].plot(kind='barh')`.